CSS transition applied through JavaScript


document.getElementById("getStartedButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".description").classList.add("hide-description"); // Add class to hide description
  document.getElementById("getStartedButton").classList.add("hide-button"); // Add class to hide button
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector(".about").classList.add("show-about"); // Add class to show 'about' section after transition ends
  }, 2000); // Adjust this time to match the duration of the transition in CSS
});
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
  /* Transition for description opacity */
}

.hide-description {
  animation: none;
  /* Remove animation for hiding description */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Hide the description */
}

@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Add your button styling here */
}

.hide-button {
  display: none;
  /* Hide the button */
}

.about {
  display: none;
  /* Initially hide the 'about' section */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay at the middle of the website */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.show-about {
  display: block;
  /* Show the 'about' section */
}
<div class="description">Yusisista Minimap is a web-based application that provides students and visitors with easy access to navigate the UCC Congress campus, allowing them to locate desired facilities, offices, and rooms with ease and efficiency.</div>

<button id="getStartedButton" class="slide">Get started</button>

<div class="about">HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</div>



I want the transition to be applied on the whole page as I click the button. i am thinking of a curtain as a reference for transition. When I click the button, the whole page will slide up, the class "description" and the button will disappear like how the page transitioned and there it will reveal the class "about"

Do not tag in the headline. Especially not with Java if you actually mean javaScript which is a completely different language.

I think I get the way you want it to be and your perfect bet would be to use transform translate as that could make you achieve what you want you can make the following adjustments based on how I feel it could work, I have attached 2 methods of doing it and honestly I like the transition one more as it gives you more freedom to work with and is a whole lot easier if you are adding JavaScript


const button = document.getElementById("getStartedButton");
const desc = document.querySelector(".description");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  desc.classList.add("hide-description"); // Add class to hide description
  button.classList.add("hide-button"); // Add class to hide button
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector(".about").classList.add("show-about"); // Add class to show 'about' section after transition ends
    desc.style.display = "none";
    button.style.display = "none";
  }, 3000); // Adjust this time to match the duration of the transition in CSS
});

// There is a delay of 1s so overall time will be 3s for this animation to occur, not much changes here
/* I have the transform translate animation will make all your stuff slide up and it we set the opacity to 0 because we aren't sure about the height and maybe if something goes wrong we do make it dissapear, we set the display to be none in javascript, that way you know it is gone */
@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateY(-190vh);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Javascript will add this class thereby it will add the animation */
.hide-description {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

.hide-button {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

/* Above was the way to achieve it with animation which is a whole lot complex */

/* This is how you would make it with transition for the about section */
.about {
  /* use opacity not display none*/
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -200vh);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%,
    rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%
  );
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* add this transition */
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* whatever you want to change goes in this class and you add it with js */
.show-about {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}



Final result is this


const button = document.getElementById("getStartedButton");
const desc = document.querySelector(".description");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  desc.classList.add("hide-description"); // Add class to hide description
  button.classList.add("hide-button"); // Add class to hide button
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector(".about").classList.add("show-about"); // Add class to show 'about' section after transition ends
    desc.style.display = "none";
    button.style.display = "none";
  }, 3000); // Adjust this time to match the duration of the transition in CSS
});
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%,
    rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%
  );
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Transition for description opacity */
}

.hide-description {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateY(-190vh);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%,
    rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%
  );
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Add your button styling here */
}

.hide-button {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

.about {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -200vh);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%,
    rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%
  );
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.show-about {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
<div class="description">Yusisista Minimap is a web-based application that provides students and visitors with easy access to navigate the UCC Congress campus, allowing them to locate desired facilities, offices, and rooms with ease and efficiency.</div>

<button id="getStartedButton" class="slide">Get started</button>

<div class="about">HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</div>




yo appreciate the help!! I used the code and it actually worked, I just modified some part.
